# Incorrect geodesic curve length on python implementation

Tags: geometry

I learned a bit of Riemannian geometry and got interested in the geodesic curve. Math is flawless, but computation is not. I will gather some requirements before going into computation implementation.

I know, there are the so-called Levi-Civitta connection coefficients that come from metric-compatibility $\nabla_c g_{ab} = 0$ required for geodesic curve definition, the Christoffel's symbols. The geodesic curve is such that the covariant derivative $\nabla$ associated with the Levi-Civitta connection of velocity vector $\dot{\gamma}$ respective to itself is zero i.e. $\nabla_\dot{\gamma} \dot{\gamma} = 0$. The representation is below.

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt} \begin{bmatrix}
\gamma^l \\ \dot{\gamma}^l
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
\dot{\gamma}^l \\ - \Gamma^l_{jk} \dot{\gamma}^j \dot{\gamma}^k
\end{bmatrix}, \gamma(0) = \gamma_0, \dot{\gamma}(0) = \dot{\gamma}_0
\end{equation}

Since we work with geodesics, the final point at dummy variable $t=1$ is the evaluated exponential map $\exp_{\gamma_0} \dot{\gamma}_0$. The curve length is given below, and do not overcomplicate using the induced norm $\lvert\lvert\cdot\rvert\rvert$ from inner product $\sqrt{\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle}$. The length of the respective geodesic curve $\gamma$ is $\langle \dot{\gamma}_0, \dot{\gamma}_0\rangle$

$$\int\limits_0^1 \lvert\lvert\dot{\gamma}\rvert\rvert \, dt = \int\limits_0^1 \sqrt{\langle\dot{\gamma}, \dot{\gamma}\rangle} \, dt$$

So far, so good. For an illustrative example, we expect on a surface $f = \begin{bmatrix} u \\ v \\ u^2 + v^2\end{bmatrix}$ to calculate metric tensor $g_{ab}$ and Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^i_{jk}$. I will spare you from tedious calculations. I place the calculated metric tensor and Christoffel symbols below for the paraboloid.

[image: metric_christoffel]

The curve length from, let me say, point $(0, 0, 0)$ to point $(1, 0, 1)$ is also equal to univariable result   $\int\limits_0^1 \sqrt{1 + \left[\frac{d}{dx}(x^2)\right]^2} dx = \int\limits_0^1 \sqrt{1 + 4 x^2} dx = \frac{1}{4} \left(2 \sqrt{5} + \mbox{arsinh}(2)\right)$, let us call $\dot{u}_0$. I expect the initial value $(0, 0)$ with initial velocity $(\dot{u}_0, 0)$ will lead to point $(u_f, 0)$ such that evaluation $f(u_f, 0) = \begin{bmatrix} u_f \\ 0 \\ u_f^2 \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$ i.e. $u_f = 1$. Since component $\dot{v}$ is always 0 for this configuration, I expected to have the norm of vector $f_u \dot{u}$ i.e. $\sqrt{1 + 4 \, u(t)^2} \, \dot{u}(t)$ always with norm $\dot{u}_0$.

Here is where my implementation flaws: on Python implementation [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ0Qx.png), I can symbolically calculate metric tensor $g$ and Christoffel symbols $\Gamma^i_{jk}$. I also used the Christoffel symbols to substitute them along the curve integration. For each time step $t_i$, I calculate the velocity $f_u \dot{u} + f_v \dot{v}$ and find its norm. Unfortunately, the result is not a constant norm but decreases over variable $t$. :/

If anyone has some idea based on the provided code on the link below, please, make me aware. This is a great achievement for me.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rQ0Qx.png) https://github.com/alloyha/experiments/blob/5b80ce8d86ddb4b98ced1addcec48ac248784778/data/geodesics/ellipsoid_geodesics.ipynb

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment.

- Not sure what the problem or the question is. It is well known that geodesics
  have unit speed only when they are parametrized by their arc length.
- It is not  a good idea to spare us from tedious calculations and let us dig out
  further details from a few hundred lines of python code in github.
- Some ideas to simplify the calculations: If you parametrize the surface
  $$
  f(u,v)=\begin{pmatrix}u\\v\\u^2+v^2\end{pmatrix}
  $$
  with polar coordinates:
  \begin{align}
  \begin{pmatrix}
  u\\
  v\\
  u^2+v^2
  \end{pmatrix}
  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  r\cos\theta\\
  r\sin\theta\\
  r^2
  \end{pmatrix}
  \end{align}
  then, if I am not mistaken, the metric induced by the Euclidean metric of $\mathbb R^3$ should become fairly simple:
  $$
  ds^2=(1+4r^2)\,dr^2+r^2\,d\theta^2\,.
  $$

Comment: Hi, Kurt, thanks for the answer. I have a computer science issue here: The scipy library does not converge to results either for initial value problem $(\gamma_0, \dot{\gamma}_0)$ nor boundary value problem $(\gamma_0, \gamma_1)$. In case you want to try yourself, you can clone the python code, I tagged on original post.

Comment: I will definitely not work on a computer science issue by cloning your code. Want to see your metric and your Christoffel symbols. In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4802161/geodesics-on-a-saddle-surface/4804749#4804749) post you see how one can handle such questions numerically.

Comment: I placed the metric tensor and Christoffel symbols on the original post.

Comment: @Usuário6789 That metric looks correct in the $u,v$ coordinates. As I recommended: switch to polar coordinates to simplify it. I don't see your Christoffel symbols. They should become considerably simpler in polar coordinates.

Comment: The Christoffel symbols is under the notation i, j, k in array format. CHeck it out!

Comment: @Usuário6789 As I said: we are still talking about math. Not about code. And I expect math notation. With `sympy.diffgeom` I get \begin{align}
{\Gamma^u}_{uu} &= {\Gamma^u}_{vv} &=\frac{4 u}{4 u^2 + 4 v^2 + 1}\,,\\
{\Gamma^v}_{uu} &= {\Gamma^v}_{vv} &=\frac{4 v}{4 u^2 + 4 v^2 + 1}\,.
\end{align} And with the metric in polar coordinates:

\begin{align}
{\Gamma^r}_{rr} &= \frac{4 r}{4 r^2 + 1}\,,&
{\Gamma^r}_{\theta\theta} &= - \frac{r}{4 r^2 + 1}\,,\\
{\Gamma^\theta}_{r\theta} &={\Gamma^\theta}_{\theta r} = \frac{1}{r}\,.
\end{align}

Comment: `christoffel_symbols[i,j,k]` $ \equiv \Gamma^i_{jk}$. As you can see by the image, there is a $\frac{1}{2}$ missing. Wish me luck. ;P

Comment: Victory! I forgot the factor $\frac{1}{2}$ on Christoffel symbols calculation. I just have to make the boundary value problem work properly now. Thanks once more, you are consistent, but probably incomplete. ;P

Comment: A good circus horse jumps only as high as it must.